# Replacing a Substring with sed

Tags: sed, text-processing, regex

So I've got a line that looks like this ish

```
somelongbullshit:888:morelongbullshitthatcanhaveanything
```

And I want to replace the second `:` with a tab character. I can reliably match the substring I want to replace with the following:

```
^.*:[0-9]*(:)
```

I want to replace that substring I have there. So I've tried doing some sed

```
$ echo somelongbullshit:888:morelongbullshitthatcanhaveanything | sed 's/:[0-9]*(:)/\1\t/g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

But I get an error. I'm sure there's some syntax error I've got wrong but for the life of me I can find it.

I'm also open to better solutions (like awk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this with `--regex-extended` switch:

```
echo somelongbullshit:888:morelongbullshitthatcanhaveanything | sed --regexp-extended 's/:[0-9]*(:)/\1\t/g'
```

Comment: This does it! Also to keep the numbers I did the following `sed --regexp-extended 's/:([0-9]*)(:)/\1\t/g`

Comment: Mahdi, The present solution has parenthesis in the wrong place...  (please see Cristogher comment).

Answer (score 0):

1. Not all versions of `sed` will recognize the tab. so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and press tab key from your keyboard.
2. use this command

   ```
    $ echo "somelongbullshit:888:morelongbullshitthatcanhaveanything" | sed 's/\:/      /2'
    somelongbullshit:888    morelongbullshitthatcanhaveanything
   ```